# How to connect to TFS on Visual Studio for Mac Release Preview

Tags: visual-studio, team-foundation-server

The only two options I can see are git and subversion. I tried entering the url using the subversion option and it did ask me for credentials but the correct credentials never worked.

Comment: Based on what you describe it does not appear Visual Studio for OS X can connect to a Team Foundation Server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TFS can use either TFVC (Team Foundation Version Control) or Git for the source control part. You don't have to use an external Git server, it has an internal one - with the data stored in the TFS SQL database. You create your first repo when you create the Team Project, but you can add repos later and you can mix TFVC and Git repos in the same Team Project - since 2015.2 I think.

Microsoft is still in the denial and marketing speak phase but TFVC is basically dead, even Microsoft is using Git for all their new repos. I'm ready to bet Visual Studio Code and Visual Studio for Mac will never connect to TFVC.

Edit: I lost my bet for Visual Studio Code, it can connect to TFVC using the [Visual Studio Team Services extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.team) since version 1.116.0 (2017/04/12).

Comment: Which is kind of a shame, because trying to collaborate on existing/legacy repos is painful, and pretty much the only thing that's worked for me is the eclipse plugin which is painful to use.

Comment: I only recently noticed you could mix Git and TFVC in the same Team Project. So Visual Studio for Mac being used for new code you create new Git repo(s) and still have everything in the same Team Project / backlog.

Comment: Yeah, been doing that for a while, but most of the code at my workplace is in a large TFVC mega repo, I've been pushing for git for new stuff.